# (FORTRAN 90) Visual Studio Watch not displaying variables, although they appear in Locals for debug mode - identifier is undefined

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I have just reloaded a project on visual studio (2019) that I was using a few days ago and the watch function in debug mode does not appear to be working anymore. I have normal debug flags (no optimisation and full debug information) and as far as I can remember I have not changed anything from the last time that I used this project (when the watch function was working normally). Apart from this, the code runs normally and without bugs.

When the code hits a breakpoint, although the local variables appear in the `locals` tab, when trying to view variables in the `watch 1` tab, all variables (even those defined locally) appear as **identifier "..." is undefined**. Hovering over variables has also stopped displaying their value.

I have tried restarting visual studio, clean and rebuild, restarting the PC, opening a different project and creating a new project, but the problem persists for all of these.

Maybe there is a switch that I have changed accidentally since the last time it was working? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this by using the visual Studio installer and using the repair option under `more`->`Repair`. After the repair and a restart, the issue was solved.